# C++ using a Garbage Collector is overkill, what is a better solution?

Tags: c++, memory-management, garbage-collection

I am currently using Boehm Garbage Collector for a large application in C++.  While it works, it seems to me that the GC is overkill for my purpose (I do not like having this as a dependency and I have to continually make allowances and think about the GC in everything I do so as to not step on its toes). I would like to find a better solution that is more suited to my needs, rather than a blanket solution that happens to cover it.

In my situation I have one specific class (and everything that inherits from that class) that I want to "collect".  I do not need general garbage collection, in all situations except for this particular class I can easily manage my own memory.

Before I started using the GC, I used reference counting, but reference cycles and the frequent updates made this a less than ideal solution.

Is there a better way for me to keep track of this class?  One that does not involve additional library dependancies like boost.

**Edit:**
It is probably best if I give a rundown on the potential lifespan of my object(s).

A function creates a new instance of my class and may (or may not) use it.  Regardless, it passes this new instance back to the caller as a return value.  The caller may (or may not) use it as well, and again it passes it back up the stack, eventually getting to the top level function which just lets the pointer fade into oblivion.

I cannot just delete the pointer in the top level, because part of the "possible use", involves passing the pointer to other functions which may (or may not) store the pointer for use somewhere else, at some future time.

I hope this better illustrates the problem that I am trying to solve.  I currently solve it with Boehm Garbage Collector, but would like simpler, non dependency involving, solution if possible.

Comment: If you want GC, why are you using C++? Switch to Java or C#

Comment: Why does `std::shared_ptr` and `std::weak_ptr` to break cycles not work?

Comment: C++ depends on you to destroy all the objects once they become unreferenced. Make a static class and keep there a list of references and counters.

Comment: @SJuan76 I do not want GC, if you read my post, the whole point is to do away with GC in all but one specific instance where its not possible for me to know the lifespan of the object.  Second, Java and C# are not just "C++ with GC" so your solution is a non-starter.

Comment: Also, if you're using a modern version of C++, it has a GC built into the standard library.  C++ in general is batteries included now.

Comment: @OmnipotentEntity I have seen mention of those in passing, but I could not understanding exactly how I could implement them to solve my problem.  Do you know of a good tutorial on these?

Comment: @OmnipotentEntity - C++ does **not** have garbage collection built into the standard library. However, there are some hooks to make it easier to write garbage-collected code.

Comment: @latreides, check out the wikipedia article on smart pointers for a good introduction.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smart_pointer  Essentially, a `shared_ptr` does reference counting and a `weak_ptr` is a shared pointer but it doesn't "own" the pointer and must be locked temporarily into a `shared_ptr` to access.  Once the reference count drops to zero, the object is deallocated as if it fell out of scope.

Comment: @latreides do you have documented ownership semantics for the objects you're creating? if the owner can hold a `std::unique_ptr` to the objects, or a container of them, when the owner goes away, so do the objects.

Comment: @OmnipotentEntity - forgot to mention: there was a proposal to add garbage collection to C++11, and it got quite a bit of discussion. It ended up being dropped because there were too many problems.

Comment: @Charlie I do not have ownership for the object. I think this prevents both your solution and the one posed by OmnipotentEntity from being viable.  If you read the edit to my original post, you can see the potential lifespan of my objects a bit better.

Comment: What do you mean you do not have ownership?  Do you get this object from a dll that's using it internally?  If so, why are and how can you be responsible for controlling the lifetime of it?

Comment: @OmnipotentEntity No, what I mean is that the function that creates an instance of an object does not own it in any form.  If I add that object to a hundred different lists, each of those lists has just as much right to the object as the others.  There is no object that has more rights to the the newly created object than any other object.  So no "parent".

Comment: That seems like an awkward design. Have you tried changing your interfaces to use std::shared_ptr everywhere? That might solve it, or do you know of cases where you end up with cycles that never get collected? What are the objects actually associated with such that you can't really name an owner? Without a concrete problem in mind, it's hard to say "oh... you should do X".

Comment: @latreides, doesn't matter, just return a `std::shared_ptr`, keep it around in the proper scopes.  When you don't need it anymore, just get rid of it by setting it to an empty shared_ptr or allowing it to simply fall out of scope.  A shared_ptr doesn't need an "owner."  It's shared :)

Comment: @Charlie The objects are not associated with anything (or maybe I do not understand your question).  They exist as independent entities.  Imagine if I created an int pointer in a function and returned the pointer and the function that received it modified it, or added it to a list, or did nothing with it, and that function returned the pointer to another function, rinse and repeat.  There is no one "owner", there is no knowing what happened to the pointer throughout its life wandering the function maze and no knowing where the pointer originated from in the first place.

Comment: @OmnipotentEntity I guess I am not sure how this is different than doing reference counting manually, and how would this solve reference cycles?  I am tempted to go back to reference counting, if I could solve reference cycles trivially (i.e. prevent them entirely, or deal with them somehow when they occur).

Comment: It's not different, other than it's built-in (less work to maintain), standard (you can tell what it's doing at a glance even if unfamiliar with the code), and potentially easier for the compiler to optimize (because it's familiar with its own library.)

Comment: @OmnipotentEntity I guess it would depend on the speed of shared_ptr vs the speed of simply overloading the new and delete operators and reference counting manually.  This still leaves the problem of reference cycles.

Comment: That's what `weak_ptrs` are for.  I assume that some how your objects own references back to the object you're working in.  If so, enforce a hierarchy, figure out which is more sensible, if object type A is missing or if object type B is missing, and assign appropriately.

Comment: @latreides when designing interfaces, typically part of the contract for a method would say "caller is responsible for cleaning this up" or specify that it's shared, or possibly that the caller is expected to use it and it's lifetime is subject to the lifetime of the object  on which the method was called. One of the ways to enforce these things is by making your return types smart pointers. Returning a `unique_ptr<T>` is an interface contract saying "caller cleans up", returning a `shared_ptr<T>` says "last one using cleans up".

Comment: @OmnipotentEntity my objects know nothing about the environment in which they were created (which is very much intentional and necessary)

Comment: @Charlie unfortunately it is not (cannot) be the responsiblity of the caller.  There is a series of complex paths that the data could take and at any time during this path the data could be passed off to another function that decides to add this pointer to its list (among other things), and many such functions could decide the same thing before we return to the "original caller" and there is no way for this original caller to know if the data is actually being used by anything else along the path or if that data is going to continue to be used long after the caller finishes.

Comment: @latreides that's exactly the use case for shared_ptr. Interfaces built on passing and returning shared_ptrs are stating "you can safely  keep a copy of this if you need to".

Comment: @Charlie I understand that but it brings us back around to reference cycles If everything is equal and uses shared_ptr.

Answer (score 1):

In the Embedded Systems world, or programs that are real-time event critical, garbage collection is frowned upon.  The point of using dynamic memory is bad.

With dynamic memory allocation, fragmentation occurs.  A Garbage Collector is used to periodically arrange memory to reduce the fragmentation, such as combining sequential freed blocks.  The primary issue is *when* to perform this defragmentation or running of the GC.

Some suggested alternatives:

**Redesign your system to avoid dynamic memory allocation.**
Allocate static buffers and use them.  For example in an RTOS system, preallocate space for messages, rather than dynamically allocating them.

**Use the Stack, not the Heap.**
Use the stack for dynamically allocated variables, if possible.  This is not a good idea if variables need a lifetime beyond the function execution.

**Place limits on variable sized data.**
Along with static buffers, place limits on variable length data or incoming data of unknown size.  This may mean that the incoming data must be paused or multiple buffering when the input cannot be stopped.

**Create your own memory allocator.**
Create many memory pools that allocate different sized blocks.  This will reduce fragmentation.  For example, for small blocks, maybe a `bitset` could be used to determine which bytes are in use and which are available.  Maybe another pool for 64 byte blocks is necessary.  All depends on your system's needs.

Comment: Avoiding dynamic memory allocation would cause significant performance hits as things are copied numerous times.  Using the stack is not a solution as there is no way to know what the lifetime of the object will be. Your other solutions would not free me from the need to manage the object manually.  I appreciate the suggestions but these will not work for me.

Answer (score 0):

If you really just need special handling for the memory allocations associated with a single class, then you should look at overloading the new operator for that class.

```
class MyClass
{
public:
  void *operator new(size_t);
  void operator delete(void *);
}
```

You can implement these operators to do whatever you need to track the memory: allocate it from a special pool, place references on a linked list for tracking, etc.

```
void* MyClass::operator new(size_t size)
{
    void *p = my_allocator(size);  // e.g., instead of malloc()
    // place p on a linked list, etc.
    return p;
}

void MyClass::operator delete(void *p)
{
    // remove p from list...
    my_free(p);
}
```

You can then write external code that can walk through the list you are keeping to inspect every currently-allocated instance of MyClass, GC'ing instances as appropriate for your situation.

Comment: The problem here is that you assume that I am keeping some list of every allocated object that I could walk through.  The number of allocated objects is limited only to the amount of memory on the target platform, so (although unlikely) it could theoretically contain hundreds of thousands of entries (even more if I wait to delete for some arbitrary time or trigger), which would not only be a memory waste, but it would be non-trivial to walk through the list as well.

Comment: @latreides - I'm actually assuming that you are *not* currently keeping a list of the allocated objects. That's the point of overloading new and delete, so that you can easily do so without touching any code outside of the object itself. The overhead of maintaining a list (or some other data structure) of these allocated objects is minimal compared to their overall heap size (and in any case, the runtime heap is already doing this whether you realize it or not). If you have so many that you need a more efficient data structure to walk them, you can use anything you wish: hash table, etc.

Comment: I do not think you understand my original question.  The question is about a better mechanism to determine if a pointer should be deleted, a point that your example code does not solve.  Maintaining a massive list (no matter the data structure) and walking such a massive list to check for things that need to be deleted, is a huge performance hit, not one that I am willing to take no matter what mechanism is in play to determine if the pointer should be deleted.  I appreciate the attempt, and if I was wondering about a good way to do reference counting, your example would be a good start.

Answer (score 0):

With memory, you should always try and have clear ownership and knowledge of lifetime. Lifetime determines where you take the memory from (as do other factors), ie stack for scope lived, pool for reused, etc. Ownership will tell you when and if to free memory. In your case, the GC has the ownership and makes the decision when to free. With ref counting, the wrapper class does this logic. Unclear ownership leads to hard to maintain code if manual memory management is used. You must avoid use after free, double frees, and memory leaking.

To solve your problem, figure out who should keep ownership. This will dictate the algoritm to use. GC and ref counting are popular choices, but there are infinetly many. If ownership is unclear, give it to a 3rd party whose job it is to keep track of it. If ownership is shared, make sure all parties are aware of it perhaps by enforcing it via specialized classes. This can also be enforced by simple convention, ie objects of type foo should never keep ptrs of type bar internally as they do not own them and if they do they cannot assume them always valid and might have to check for validity first. Etc.

If you find this hard to determine, it could be a sign that the code is very complex. Could it be made in a more simple manner?

Understanding how your memory is used and accessed is key to writing clean code for maintenance and performance optimizations. This is true regardless of language used.

Best of luck.